# Erro ao preencher ListView em uma thread (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, listview, thread, firemonkey

Em um projeto mobile tenho um trecho de código que preenche um ListView com os dados de um DataSet (não estou usando LiveBindings). Até um certo momento tudo estava funcionando bem até que resolvi adicionar uma animação durante o carregamento da lista e coloquei o trecho de carregamento dentro de uma thread conforme mostro mais abaixo.
O fato é que o carregamento tornou-se instável pois em alguns momentos executa normal e em outros executa parcialmente e o debug retorna o erro "raised exception class Segmentation fault (11)".
Aqui está o código:

```
procedure TViewPesquisaCliente.PreencherListaClientes;
var
  oItem: TListViewItem;
  oId, oCodigo, oNome, oCPF: TListItemText;
  oClientes: TDataSet;
begin
  TLoading.Show(ViewPesquisaCliente, 'Carregando lista de clientes...');

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin
    try
      oClientes := TControllerCliente.New.Clientes;
      lstLista.Items.Clear;
      lstLista.BeginUpdate;
      oClientes.Open;

      while not oClientes.Eof do
      begin
        oItem := lstLista.Items.Add;
        oId := TListItemText(oItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Id'));
        oCodigo := TListItemText(oItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Codigo'));
        oNome := TListItemText(oItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Nome'));
        oCPF := TListItemText(oItem.Objects.FindDrawable('CPF'));
        oId.Text := oClientes.FieldByName('Id').AsString;
        oCodigo.Text := oClientes.FieldByName('Codigo').AsString;
        oNome.Text := oClientes.FieldByName('Nome').AsString;
        oCPF.Text := oClientes.FieldByName('CPF').AsString;
        oClientes.Next;
      end;
    finally
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        TLoading.Hide;
      end);

      lstLista.EndUpdate;
      oClientes.Close;
      oClientes.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end
  ).Start;
end;
```

O trecho TLoading.Show carrega a animação da tela antes de iniciar o preenchimento da lista e TLoading.Hide encerra a animação.
Não tenho experiência com threads e segundo algumas pesquisas que li o problema pode estar em tentar manipular os objetos da tela dentro da thread. Eu até comentei o trecho da linha "oId.Text := " até "oCPF.Text := " e voltou a funcionar, mas o ListView fica em branco, então estou com esse problema.
Alguém teria uma sugestão?

Comment: Quando eu fazia um loading... eu usava o `timer` acho mais fácil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não deve fazer manipulação de objectos visuais dentro de uma thread, muito menos em mobile.
Toda a parte que involve componente visual deve estar dentro do synchronize ou de um queue, para que garantidamente seja executado na main thread.

Neste caso sugeria que tentasse um Synchronize ao inicio (como tem no finally) para o items.clear e o beginupdate da lista, e incluir o  lstLista.EndUpdate; dentro do ultimo synchronize.

Aconselho tambem a ver o Queue que pode ser uma boa alternativa pois nao tranca a thread à espera que a main thread faça o codigo pretendido.

Comment: A princípio eu consegui resolver o problema dando um Visible := False antes de iniciar a atualização do ListView e um Visible := True após sair da thread, mas sei que não é uma solução "elegante". Vou estudar essa sua abordagem e tentar aplicá-la ao meu código. Obrigado.

Comment: Pouco convencional :D mas se funcionou já não é mau :D